# Sorting based on string java

Tags: java, sorting

I have a `list` of objects that I need to sort based on a `string`.

each object in list would contain the below

```
e.g.
fruitType = Pear
fruitType = Mango
fruitType = Apple
fruitType = Apple
fruitType = Mango
```

Now, say i want to order by '`Apple`' first and then by '`Mango`'. So apple comes on top first followed by mango.

I can do a normal sort asc/desc but that is not sufficient. Also is possible to use apache commons to do the above sort?

Comment: Write your own comparable and use Treeset?  And what do you mean, asc/desc is not sufficient?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? What does a list of objects mean? Are they `String`, custom objects or `Object`?

Comment: If i was to sort the above list in asc order I would get the result I want. I want to see an example on how to sort based on a particular string so it pushes the element you give it to the top in the list without sorting on asc/desc. (not sure if i'm going down the wrong path with this?)

Comment: No you dont, all you want to do is google for something like "java compare tutorial" and youre all good. You want to implement the comparable interface to compare for example a Fruit to another Fruit by its fruitType (or say its weight+length or something else). After you have a Comparator aware on how to compare your Objects you can use Collections.sort or something similar to do the acctual sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
    private String whatYouWantToSortBy;
    ...
    public int compareTo(Fruit other) {
        return whatYouWantToSortBy.compareTo(other.whatYouWantToSortBy);
    }
}
```

To sort, use `Collections.sort`.  Or you can just use a type of List that automatically sorts itself, like TreeSet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort on a predefined order (i.e., you've got some fixed ordering of strings in mind), then you could do it like this:

1. Set up a `HashMap<String,Integer> sortTable`. Into it, you put all your strings, and map each one to its index in the sort order. If you want `Apple` first, then `Mango`, then `Plum`, etc., then you add these: `sortTable.put("Apple",0); sortTable.put("Mango",1); sortTable.put("Plum",2);` and so on.
2. Now write your `Comparator` as follows. When you compare two `String` instances `s` and `t`, you look both up in your `HashMap` and compare them by the value they map to. So if you're comparing `Apple` and `Plum`, you look up `Apple` and find it maps to `0`; you look up `Plum` and you find it maps to `2`; and you then `return Integer.compare(0,2)`.

In other words, your `Comparator` uses:

```
public int compare(String x, String y) {
    return Integer.compare(sortTable.get(x), sortTable.get(y));
}
```

This will allow you to use `Collections.sort` on your list, passing it the `Comparator` you've created.

Note that you need either some policy to deal with `String`s that aren't in your predefined list, or some guarantee that that will never happen.